# Moving probability and moving average for specific numbers in multiple columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a panel dataset that looks like the below.

```
+----+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | t | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4 | value_5 | value_6 | value_7 | value_8 | value_9 |
+----+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 1 | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 2 | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 2 | 2       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 3 | 2       | 2       | 5       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 4 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 5 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 6 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 7 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | NA      | NA      |
|  1 | 8 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | NA      |
|  1 | 9 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
|  2 | 0 | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 1 | 5       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 2 | 5       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 3 | 5       | 2       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 4 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 5 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 6 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 7 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | NA      | NA      |
|  2 | 8 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | NA      |
|  2 | 9 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
+----+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Using this dataset, I would like to create two new variables based on number 2 and 7 (don't consider number 5 at all) in columns *value_1 to value_9*.

1. **probcount_2**: When `t<=1`, this is always equal to 0.5 but for `t>1` it calculates the running probability of number 2 (from the columns *value_1 to value_9* that include number 2 and 7).
2. **average_ 27**: When `t<=1`, this is always equal to 4.5 (average of 2 and 7) but for `t>1` it calculates the running average of 2 and 7 (from the columns *value_1 to value_9* that include number 2 and 7).

I am aiming for the below output.

```
+----+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
| id | t | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4 | value_5 | value_6 | value_7 | value_8 | value_9 | probcount_2 | average_27 |
+----+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | 1 | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |         0.5 |        4.5 |
|  1 | 2 | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  1 | 2 | 2       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  1 | 3 | 2       | 2       | 5       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  1 | 4 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  1 | 5 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |        0.75 |       3.25 |
|  1 | 6 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      |        0.60 |          4 |
|  1 | 7 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | NA      | NA      |        0.66 |        3.7 |
|  1 | 8 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | NA      |        0.71 |       3.45 |
|  1 | 9 | 2       | 2       | 5       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | 2       |        0.75 |       3.25 |
|  2 | 0 | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |         0.5 |        4.5 |
|  2 | 1 | 5       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |         0.5 |        4.5 |
|  2 | 2 | 5       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  2 | 3 | 5       | 2       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  2 | 4 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |           1 |          2 |
|  2 | 5 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      | NA      |        0.75 |       3.25 |
|  2 | 6 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | NA      | NA      | NA      |        0.60 |          4 |
|  2 | 7 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | NA      | NA      |        0.66 |        3.7 |
|  2 | 8 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | NA      |        0.71 |       3.45 |
|  2 | 9 | 5       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 7       | 7       | 2       | 2       | 2       |        0.75 |       3.25 |
+----+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you write any code so far?

Comment: I stuck in mutate in dplyr.

Comment: It is equal to average(2,2,2,7)=3.25, as I mentioned that I would like to consider only 2 and 7 (and discard 5).

Comment: I would approach this by using `tidyr::gather(col, val, value_1:value_9)` to pull into long form, then `dplyr::group_by(id, t)`, then `dplyr::filter(val %in% c(2, 7))` and then summarize to get your two summary columns. As a last step, join back to the original data.

Comment: Yes, it should be 1 but it happens with those observations when ```t``` is not distinct. Also, I cannot use ```group_by``` because all these observations coming from the one id. So my best bet would be to have the same values for ```probcount_2``` and ```average_27```  when ```t``` is the same and different when ```t``` is different.

Comment: There was a bit of an issue with my data which I have figured it out and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are interested only in values 2 & 7 we can change rest of values to `NA` and then perform the calculations. Using `dplyr` that can be done as

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("value")), ~replace(., !. %in% c(2, 7), NA)) %>%
  mutate(probcount_2 = ifelse(t <= 1, 0.5, 
        rowSums(.[3:11] == 2, na.rm = TRUE)/rowSums(!is.na(.[3:11]), na.rm = TRUE)),
         average_27 = ifelse(t <= 1, 4.5, rowMeans(.[3:11], na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  select(id, t, probcount_2, average_27)


#   id t probcount_2 average_27
#1   1 1       0.500       4.50
#2   1 2       1.000       2.00
#3   1 2       1.000       2.00
#4   1 3       1.000       2.00
#5   1 4       1.000       2.00
#6   1 5       0.750       3.25
#7   1 6       0.600       4.00
#8   1 7       0.667       3.67
#9   1 8       0.714       3.43
#10  1 9       0.750       3.25
#11  2 0       0.500       4.50
#12  2 1       0.500       4.50
#13  2 2       1.000       2.00
#14  2 3       1.000       2.00
#15  2 4       1.000       2.00
#16  2 5       0.750       3.25
#17  2 6       0.600       4.00
#18  2 7       0.667       3.67
#19  2 8       0.714       3.43
#20  2 9       0.750       3.25
```

Comment: it does most of the job, except in some case when ```t``` has the same number. Please see below

Comment: Please see the updated question. I have included the problem with the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `base R`, an option would be to loop over the rows, extract the elements that are 2 or 7, get the `mean` of logical vector ('i1') and the `mean` of the subset of values

```
df[c("probcount_2", "average_27")] <- t(apply(df[-(1:2)], 1, 
    function(x) {
      x1 <- x[x %in% c(2, 7)]
      i1 <- x1 == 2
      c(if(length(i1) == 0) 0.5 else mean(i1),
        if(length(i1) ==0) 4.5 else mean(x1))
     }))

df
#   id t value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5 value_6 value_7 value_8 value_9 probcount_2 average_27
#1   1 1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   0.5000000   4.500000
#2   1 2       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#3   1 2       2       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#4   1 3       2       2       5      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#5   1 4       2       2       5       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#6   1 5       2       2       5       2       7      NA      NA      NA      NA   0.7500000   3.250000
#7   1 6       2       2       5       2       7       7      NA      NA      NA   0.6000000   4.000000
#8   1 7       2       2       5       2       7       7       2      NA      NA   0.6666667   3.666667
#9   1 8       2       2       5       2       7       7       2       2      NA   0.7142857   3.428571
#10  1 9       2       2       5       2       7       7       2       2       2   0.7500000   3.250000
#11  2 0      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   0.5000000   4.500000
#12  2 1       5      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   0.5000000   4.500000
#13  2 2       5       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#14  2 3       5       2       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#15  2 4       5       2       2       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   1.0000000   2.000000
#16  2 5       5       2       2       2       7      NA      NA      NA      NA   0.7500000   3.250000
#17  2 6       5       2       2       2       7       7      NA      NA      NA   0.6000000   4.000000
#18  2 7       5       2       2       2       7       7       2      NA      NA   0.6666667   3.666667
#19  2 8       5       2       2       2       7       7       2       2      NA   0.7142857   3.428571
#20  2 9       5       2       2       2       7       7       2       2      2    0.7500000   3.250000
```

---

Or we can vectorize with `rowMeans`

```
m1 <- replace(as.matrix(df[-(1:2)]), !as.matrix(df[-(1:2)]) %in% c(2, 7), NA)
df$probcount_2 <- rowMeans(m1 == 2, na.rm = TRUE)
df$average_27  <- rowMeans(m1, na.rm = TRUE)
i1 <- df$t <= 1
df[i1, c("probcount_2", "average_27")] <- list(0.5, 4.5)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), t = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L
), value_1 = c(NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), value_2 = c(NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), value_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, NA, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), value_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), value_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), value_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), value_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L), value_8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L
), value_9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```